# How to redirect to home page after submitting the Contact Form?

Tags: php

i have created contact form but i am getting two problems

1. Reply-To mail is not going.
2. After Submitting the form page has to redirect to Home page.

For reference please find the attached image and code

[image]

Below is the PHP code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name']; // Get Name value from HTML Form
    $email_id = $_POST['email']; // Get Email Value
    $mobile_no = $_POST['Mobile']; // Get Mobile No
    $msg = $_POST['message']; // Get Message Value
     
    $to = "somasekhar.n@vitalticks.com"; // You can change here your Email
    $subject = "'$name' has been sent a mail"; // This is your subject
     
    // HTML Message Starts here
    $message ="
    <html>
        <body>
            <table style='width:600px;'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='width:150px'><strong>Name: </strong></td>
                        <td style='width:400px'>$name</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='width:150px'><strong>Email ID: </strong></td>
                        <td style='width:400px'>$email_id</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='width:150px'><strong>Mobile No: </strong></td>
                        <td style='width:400px'>$mobile_no</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='width:150px'><strong>Message: </strong></td>
                        <td style='width:400px'>$msg</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
    ";
    // HTML Message Ends here
     
    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= "From: New Contact Form <".$_POST["email"].">\r\n"; // Give an email id on which you want get a reply. User will get a mail from this email id
    $headers .= 'Cc: somumstr210@gmail.com' . "\r\n"; // If you want add cc
   // $headers .= 'Bcc: somasekhar.n@vitalticks.com' . "\r\n"; // If you want add Bcc
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
     
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
        // Message if mail has been sent
        echo "<script>
                alert('Mail has been sent Successfully.');
            </script>";
    }

    else{
        // Message if mail has been not sent
        echo "<script>
                alert('EMAIL FAILED');
            </script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: So which question is it? Ask one question at a time on stackoverflow.

Comment: Since you already set `$email_id = $_POST['email'];` why not just use `$email_id` throughout the rest of the script rather than `$_POST['email']` Also, does the email get sent?

Comment: Check your log for errors

Answer (score 0):

1. The mail function is deprecated and may not work right! I recommand phpmailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
2. [How do I make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php)

   header("Location: path/to/file");
3. please check post variables

   $variable = $_POST['variable-name'] ?? "default content if $_POST['variable-name'] is undefined";

EDIT: mail() is not deprecated but please use the PHPmailer because it's better